# XeLaTeX with tikz external library produces pdfs of wrong size

Tags: xetex, tikz-external, shell-escape

I am trying to use `TikZ` and its `external` library together with `XeLaTeX` for example in this MWE where I use `scrbook` for compatibility to my large document, where the error occurs.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX TS-options = -shell-escape
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[up to date check=diff]
\tikzset{external/system call={xelatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
\begin{document}
  \tikzsetnextfilename{tikz-export-xelatex-temp}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick,blue] (0,0) -- (5,5) -- (0,5) -- (5,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Deleting the first line (which tells my TextMate to use xelatex), lines 4,5 (the font-packages of `xelatex`), and 9 (the modified system call for `xelatex` shell-escape-calls), the example produces a nice 5-by-5 cm PDF calles `tikz-expoer-xelatex-temp.pdf` in the corresponding folder.

However, when compiling this code with `xelatex`, the PDF (named as above) also also produced but is not of size 5-by-5cm but full DinA4. When this is included into the document on the second run (the main reason for `externalize`), it looks rather strange.

I am running MacTeX 2015 (TeXLive 2015) on Mac OS 10.11.2 and use TextMate for editing.

So my questions are

Why does `xelatex` seem to be unable to determine the size of the `tikzpicture`?
How can I solve this and use `external` with `xelatex` properly?

*Update*
For completeness here's my filelist (`\listfiles` in the preamble)

```
 *File List*
 scrbook.cls    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script document class (book)
scrkbase.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent ba
sics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (type area)
fontspec.sty    2015/09/24 v2.4e Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
   expl3.sty    2015/11/04 v6224 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2015/11/04 v6224 L3 programming layer 
l3unicode-data.def    2015/07/20 v5676 L3 Unicode data
l3xdvipdfmx.def    
  xparse.sty    2015/11/04 v6224 L3 Experimental document command parser
fontspec-patches.sty    2015/09/24 v2.4e Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
fontspec-xetex.sty    2015/09/24 v2.4e Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
  eu1enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
  eu1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
xunicode.sty    2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many oth
er characters in Unicode lower plane
 eu1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
   xetex.def    2015/09/11 v4.06 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (TeX Liv
e/RRM/JK)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
fontspec.cfg
 xltxtra.sty    2010/09/20 v0.5e Improvements for the "XeLaTeX" format
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
realscripts.sty    2013/03/18 v0.3c Access OpenType subscripts and superscripts

metalogo.sty    2010/05/29 v0.12 Extended TeX logo macros
    tikz.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)
     pgf.sty    2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)
  pgfrcs.sty    2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
  pgfsys.sty    2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
   t3cmr.fd    2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
```

*Update #2*
I changed the call of `\tikzexternalize` to use `check=diff` in order to avoid a warning on Mac OS.

*Update #3*
Following @jfbu s remarks I updated my packages using the `TeX Live Utility` (after updating the path to the executables for Mac OS el Capitan to `/Library/TeX/texbin/`) and with the updated filelist (see above), the problem still exists.

Comment: Apart from warning `Package tikz Warning: The key 'up to date check=md5' is impossible`, this compiles fine on my (more or less uptodate) TL2015 with `xelatex` and the `pdf` has the dimensions of the drawing.

Comment: and this is also on Mac OS but Mavericks . Is your TL2105 up-to-date ?

Comment: Oh I have that warning, too, yes. And up-to-date - well it's the MacTeX2015 package...maybe i'll try to also state the package versions I have (just have to check for the command to do that.

Comment: MacTeX comes with [TeX Live Utility application](http://amaxwell.github.io/tlutility/) (check if present in your `/Applications`) With it you can update your installation.

Comment: That's a good idea - however due to the change of the directories in El Capitan, I will have to look how to get that Application running again on El Capitan :/

Comment: If you installed `MacTeX` under El Capitan, you should have that application already. (I think).

Comment: There is no more a `/Applications` under `El Capitan` ???

Comment: Oh, hehe, well there is. There is no `/usr/texbin/` anymore and I had to check for the new directoy ( `/Library/TeX/texbin/`) and now the updates are running.

Comment: hmm... I would be surprised that `Tex Live Utility` ended up being in `/Library/TeX/texbin/`... You should not have to check for that repertory but only possibly reconfigure previous tex aware apps to use it. See http://tug.org/mactex/elcapitan.html Anyway, as you say updates are running all is fine then.

Comment: No, but all command line programs the `TeX Live Utility` needs - I had to update the preferences of the utility. But - updating all packages didn't help, the problem persists.

Comment: Your installation is not at all up-to-date. If I compare with what `\listfiles` on my installation produces there are numerous differences. For example I have `KOMA-script v3.19a` and yours is `3.17a`. You have a ``xetex.def    2015/03/25 v4.04 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (TeX Live/RRM/JK)`` which on my system is  ``xetex.def    2015/09/11 v4.06 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (TeX Live/RRM/JK)``. Your version of `TikZ` dates back to `2013/12`, mine from `2015/08`.

Comment: That was before the update - sorry, i'll update the filelist tomorrow morning.

Comment: ah ok, sorry I should have paid more attention to the chronology of your edit to the answer and your comment. Hope that after the update it will compile satisfactorily on your system.

Comment: Nevermind. Now I updated the filelist to the updated package versions but still have the same problem.

Comment: Yours: ``tikz.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)``, mine:  ``tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)``. Similar differences for pgf related style files. I don't know why, but your TikZ/pgf is not updated. I have no idea whether ghostscript is involved, but maybe worth mentioning mine is `GPL Ghostscript 9.16 (2015-03-30)` which I installed via Fink.

Comment: Hm, that's interesting, because I really just updated to the most recent versions with the TeX Live Utility.

Comment: check the log for where `tikz.sty` is found. Perhaps you have it in `texmf-local` ?

Comment: Oh! You're right, i manually updated long time ago to a 3.0.0 due to a bug in the 2.x in my local tree - removing those solved the bug. Thank you very much for your patience.

Comment: good to learn it does work now.

Comment: I checked and it really seems to be TikZ 3.0.0 - so if you want, you can turn your remarks & tips into an answer and i am happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem does not currently arise with an up-to-date TeX installation, (in particular `tikz.sty 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)`).

From OP's comments, an up-to-date installation but having a more ancient `TikZ/pgf` (`tikz.sty 2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)`) in a local tree hiding the newer release does display the problem.